# Does Python support function overloading with multiple signatures with different number of positional arguments?

Tags: python, overloading

Python doesn't seem to support function overloading:

```
>>> def overload(x,y):
...     return x*y
... 
>>> def overload(x,y,z):
...     return x*y*z
... 
>>> overload(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: overload() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>>> overload(1,2,3)
6
>>>
```

Is it just for a specific version of python or python never supports function overloading?

Comment: Python does not support overloading the way you are trying to use it.

Comment: No it doesn't, and if you search, this has been answered many times before.

Comment: It doesn't support overloading by allowing multiple signatures with different number of positional args. But you can get overloading by using keyword args where the optional extra args have defaults supplied: `def overload(x,y,z=1): return x*y*z` works for this case